# PayPal Express Error: Unexpected token S in JSON at position 0

Tags: php, json, paypal

I am integrating PayPal express checkout (server-side) in my PHP website. While I am integrating the PayPal express popup is not opening and it is giving me "Unexpected token S in JSON at position 0" in the console. Here is the screenshot https://prnt.sc/10f10qi

Here is HTML code:

```
<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=<client-id>"></script>
<script>
    paypal.Buttons({
        createOrder: function() {
          return fetch('paypal/create-payment.php', {
            method: 'post',
            headers: {
              'content-type': 'application/json'
            }
          }).then(function(res) {
            return res.json();
          }).then(function(data) {
            return data.id;
          });
        },
        onAuthorize: function(data, actions) {
          return actions.payment.execute().then(function() {
            alert(data.orderID);
          });
        }
    }).render('#paypal-button');
</script>
<div id="paypal-button"></div>
```

Here is the server side code for create-payment.php

```
<?php

namespace Sample\CaptureIntentExamples;

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
//1. Import the PayPal SDK client that was created in `Set up Server-Side SDK`.
use Sample\PayPalClient;
use PayPalCheckoutSdk\Orders\OrdersCreateRequest;
require 'paypal-client.php';
class CreateOrder
{

// 2. Set up your server to receive a call from the client
  /**
   *This is the sample function to create an order. It uses the
   *JSON body returned by buildRequestBody() to create an order.
   */
  public static function createOrder($debug=false)
  {
    $request = new OrdersCreateRequest();
    $request->prefer('return=representation');
    $request->body = self::buildRequestBody();
   // 3. Call PayPal to set up a transaction
    $client = PayPalClient::client();
    $response = $client->execute($request);
    if ($debug)
    {
      print "Status Code: {$response->statusCode}\n";
      print "Status: {$response->result->status}\n";
      print "Order ID: {$response->result->id}\n";
      print "Intent: {$response->result->intent}\n";
      print "Links:\n";
      foreach($response->result->links as $link)
      {
        print "\t{$link->rel}: {$link->href}\tCall Type: {$link->method}\n";
      }

      // To print the whole response body, uncomment the following line
      // echo json_encode($response->result, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    }

    // 4. Return a successful response to the client.
    return $response;
  }

  /**
     * Setting up the JSON request body for creating the order with minimum request body. The intent in the
     * request body should be "AUTHORIZE" for authorize intent flow.
     *
     */
    private static function buildRequestBody()
    {
        return array(
            'intent' => 'CAPTURE',
            'application_context' =>
                array(
                    'return_url' => 'https://example.com/return',
                    'cancel_url' => 'https://example.com/cancel'
                ),
            'purchase_units' =>
                array(
                    0 =>
                        array(
                            'amount' =>
                                array(
                                    'currency_code' => 'USD',
                                    'value' => '220.00'
                                )
                        )
                )
        );
    }
}


/**
 *This is the driver function that invokes the createOrder function to create
 *a sample order.
 */
if (!count(debug_backtrace()))
{
  CreateOrder::createOrder(true);
}
?>
```

Please let me know what I am doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Is `$debug` being set to `true`? That'd explain the `S` (`print "Status Code...`)

Comment: $debug is false. I've set its value false in function  public static function createOrder($debug=false)

Comment: Ah sorry, should have referred directly to my concerns being raised by `CreateOrder::createOrder(true);`